# Pandas dataframe finding largest N elements of each row with row-specific N

Tags: pandas, dataframe, max, rowwise

I have a DataFrame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'row1' : [1,2,np.nan,4,5], 'row2' : [11,12,13,14,np.nan], 'row3':[22,22,23,24,25]}, index = 'a b c d e'.split()).T
>>> df
         a     b     c     d     e
row1   1.0   2.0   NaN   4.0   5.0
row2  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0   NaN
row3  22.0  22.0  23.0  24.0  25.0
```

and a Series that specifies the number of top N values I want from each row

```
>>> n_max = pd.Series([2,3,4])
```

What is Panda's way of using `df` and `n_max` to find the largest N elements of each (breaking ties with a random pick, just as `.nlargest()` would do)?

The desired output is

```
         a     b     c     d     e
row1   NaN   NaN   NaN   4.0   5.0
row2   NaN  12.0  13.0  14.0   NaN
row3  22.0   NaN  23.0  24.0  25.0
```

I know how to do this with a uniform/fixed N across all rows (say, N=4). Note the tie-breaking in row3:

```
>>> df.stack().groupby(level=0).nlargest(4).unstack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reindex(columns=df.columns)
         a     b     c     d     e
row1   1.0   2.0   NaN   4.0   5.0
row2  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0   NaN
row3  22.0   NaN  23.0  24.0  25.0
```

But the goal, again, is to have row-specific `N`. Looping through each row obviously doesn't count (for performance reasons). And I've tried using `.rank()` with a mask but tie breaking doesn't work there...

Comment: `row3` has the second element `NaN-ed`, whereas the first element has tie with it. So, any reason why the second elem was picked? Does it matter if either of those were picked?

Comment: It doesn't matter. That's exactly why I commented the behavior of `.nlargest()` which has that random tie break function.

Comment: `.rank` has a `method` parameter that handles all sort of "ties".

Comment: @ScottBoston, thank you. That tip alone solved my problem. I'll use `method='first'`.

Comment: Since, we were looking for performance, did you check out this post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/44074289/3293881 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @ScottBoston's comment on the OP, it is possible to use the following mask based on rank to solve this problem:

```
>>> n_max.index = df.index
>>> df_rank = df.stack(dropna=False).groupby(level=0).rank(ascending=False, method='first').unstack()
>>> selected = df_rank.le(n_max, axis=0)
>>> df[selected]
         a     b     c     d     e
row1   NaN   NaN   NaN   4.0   5.0
row2   NaN  12.0  13.0  14.0   NaN
row3  22.0   NaN  23.0  24.0  25.0
```

Answer (score 1):

For performance, I would suggest NumPy -

```
def mask_variable_largest_per_row(df, n_max):
    a = df.values
    m,n = a.shape

    nan_row_count = np.isnan(a).sum(1)
    n_reset = n-n_max.values-nan_row_count
    n_reset.clip(min=0, max=n-1, out = n_reset)

    sidx = a.argsort(1)
    mask = n_reset[:,None] > np.arange(n)

    c = sidx[mask]
    r = np.repeat(np.arange(m), n_reset)
    a[r,c] = np.nan
    return df
```

Sample run -

```
In [182]: df
Out[182]: 
         a     b     c     d     e
row1   1.0   2.0   NaN   4.0   5.0
row2  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0   NaN
row3  22.0  22.0   5.0  24.0  25.0

In [183]: n_max = pd.Series([2,3,2])

In [184]: mask_variable_largest_per_row(df, n_max)
Out[184]: 
       a     b     c     d     e
row1 NaN   NaN   NaN   4.0   5.0
row2 NaN  12.0  13.0  14.0   NaN
row3 NaN   NaN   NaN  24.0  25.0
```

**Further boost :** Bringing in `numpy.argpartition` to replace the `numpy.argsort` should help, as we don't care about the order of indices to be reset as `NaNs`. Thus, a `numpy.argpartition` based one would be -

```
def mask_variable_largest_per_row_v2(df, n_max):
    a = df.values
    m,n = a.shape

    nan_row_count = np.isnan(a).sum(1)
    n_reset = n-n_max.values-nan_row_count
    n_reset.clip(min=0, max=n-1, out = n_reset)

    N = (n-n_max.values).max()
    N = np.clip(N, a_min=0, a_max=n-1)

    sidx = a.argpartition(N, axis=1) #sidx = a.argsort(1)
    mask = n_reset[:,None] > np.arange(n)

    c = sidx[mask]
    r = np.repeat(np.arange(m), n_reset)
    a[r,c] = np.nan
    return df
```

**Runtime test**

Other approaches -

```
def pandas_rank_based(df, n_max):
    n_max.index = df.index
    df_rank = df.stack(dropna=False).groupby(level=0).rank\
               (ascending=False, method='first').unstack()
    selected = df_rank.le(n_max, axis=0)
    return df[selected]
```

Verification and timings -

```
In [387]: arr = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
     ...: arr.ravel()[np.random.choice(arr.size, 10000, replace=0)] = np.nan
     ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr)
     ...: df2 = df1.copy()
     ...: df3 = df1.copy()
     ...: n_max = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,1000,(1000)))
     ...: 
     ...: out1 = pandas_rank_based(df1, n_max)
     ...: out2 = mask_variable_largest_per_row(df2, n_max)
     ...: out3 = mask_variable_largest_per_row_v2(df3, n_max)
     ...: print np.nansum(out1-out2)==0 # Verify
     ...: print np.nansum(out1-out3)==0 # Verify
     ...: 
True
True

In [388]: arr = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
     ...: arr.ravel()[np.random.choice(arr.size, 10000, replace=0)] = np.nan
     ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr)
     ...: df2 = df1.copy()
     ...: df3 = df1.copy()
     ...: n_max = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,1000,(1000)))
     ...: 

In [389]: %timeit pandas_rank_based(df1, n_max)
1 loops, best of 3: 559 ms per loop

In [390]: %timeit mask_variable_largest_per_row(df2, n_max)
10 loops, best of 3: 34.1 ms per loop

In [391]: %timeit mask_variable_largest_per_row_v2(df3, n_max)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.92 ms per loop
```

Pretty good speedups there of **`50x+`** over the pandas built-in!